# Anchor ImageView position to another ImageView which is being scaled

Tags: android, xml, scale

I got this layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/rel2"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/lemon_large"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
  <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/fruit"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/lemonpiece"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tree"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tree"
      android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="136dp"/>
```

The tree is being scaled, the top and bottom is always cropped. This is because of a screens variability in height. What I wanna do, is to have fixed image view, which are always in the same place relative to the image view no matter how much it is being scaled.

Ive tried different scaleType values, but it always actually scales the image and on every screen the image is somewhere else relative to the "tree".

Another possibility I tried is to align it to the top of the screen (alignParentTop, alignParentLeft, scaleType="matrix") but this wont work as since as some screens are very short and then the picture wont fit into the screen properly. In other words, I need to preserve the scalability and to anchor the top images.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Resource XML file for Dimensions, and put the following,

**image_dimens.xml:**

```
<dimen name="myValueX">95dp</dimen>
<dimen name="myValueY">136dp</dimen>
```

**In your Activity displaying ImageViews:**

```
    int myValueX = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.myValueX);
    int myValueX = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.myValueX);

    ImageView ivFruit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fruit);
    ImageView ivTree = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tree);
    ivFruit.setX(ivTree.getX() + myValueX);
    ivFruit.setY(ivTree.getY() + myValueY);
```

Hope this helps, Happy Coding!

Comment: Hi there, this wont work. I need first to know how much was the "tree" scaled and then actually multiply the scaling ratio with the fixed margins... Any ideas how to do that?